# I bet u can not find the word/phrase hidden in this post!

Tags: wordplay, cipher, steganography, letters

there Is a word/phrase Nefariously inserted into this question/post.
Can you find it?
i do indeed hope this puzzle will fasinate you Or at least Retain your interest for a while!
i Really enjoyed making this puzzle; hopefully you will Enjoy solving it just as much!
i am very sorry if my inglish isn't perfect in this post, but alas, it may help you in solving.
i am Creating this post on wenesday july 1st, can you solve it before the fifth?
be warned: there is alot of difficulty.
so therefore, my deer friends, i will start you off with a hint: i have, in some way, used the word/phrase in this post.
To be honest, i hope you do not get an answer that is incorrect!
good luck!

Hint 1 (6/3):

> Spelling errors are there for a reason.

Hint 2 (6/5):

> Think of the missing letters...

Comment: Don't bother trying to fix the english lol :)

Comment: rot13(Gjb fcnprf nsgre rnpu fragrapr)

Comment: @Mordechai rot13(Gur gjb fcnprf nsgre rnpu fragrapr vf whfg gb znxr n arj yvar sbe nfgurgvp checbfrf (Gung'f ubj fgnpx rkpunatr'f grkg sbezng jbexf)... bgurejvfr vg jbhyq whfg ybbx yvxr n tvnag obevat pbashfvat cnentencu.)

Comment: Are you sure [tag:cryptic-clues] is accurate? It refers to a specific type of crossword clue that can be split into definition and wordplay.

Comment: I thought it was but to be honest, you would know more than me so i'll remove it. @Deusovi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

> "A Decoy"

With the hint in mind,

> You can take the missing letters from the misspelled words (u, fasinated, inglish, wenesday, alot and deer), to get "**yo + c + e + d + "space" + a**".

Then

> You can take the anagram of "yoced a" to get "**A Decoy**".

This fits with clues because:

> It is not the obvious answer, as stated by the clues.
>  There is a decoy used in the form of the obvious answer of "INCORRECT"

Comment: I cannot say if this is correct or not until you tell me how I used it in the problem

Comment: @Ankit rot13(Vf gur "qrpbl" gur nafjre bs "Vapbeerpg"(sebz gur pncvgnyvmrq yrggref) gur qrpbl?)

Comment: Lrf gung vf pbeerpg, V'z chggvat na rqvg va lbhe nafjre

Comment: @Ankit Shouldn't this answer be accepted and the bounty awarded to QuantumTwinkie?

Comment: @BarryPoppins Sorry I was busy at work and forgot. I just accepted. I hope you enjoyed the puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

Second attempt:

> The initial of the misspelt words (fasinated, inglish, wenesday, alot, deer) spell out "fiwad"

If you let Google Translate detect the language it turns out that

> "fiwad" means "farewell" in Somali

Where did you use it?

> You end the post with a "good luck": "farewell" is literally a wish of good luck on a journey.

My first answer was too trivial, this one is totally bonkers. It is left to the reader to decide which is worse

Comment: This answer is also incorrect. You are a lot closer than I had expected someone to come after just a few hours though so good job. You are on the right track. Although your answer was incorrect, I like the ingenuity so i gave you a +1.

Comment: Yay, I have never been on the right track before! I mean, in life, not just in puzzling. Still stuck and waiting for an epiphany though...

Answer (score 3):

May be too simple to be the right answer, but is it:

> Incorrect?

Reason

> The capital letters spell the word "incorrect", it is used in the last sentence and the English used is indeed "incorrect"

Comment: Although I know think that rot13( "V ubcr lbh qb abg trg na nafjre gung vf vapbeerpg!" zvtug zrna gung "vapbeerpg" vf abg gur nafjre lbh ner ybbxvat sbe). Me sad...

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. haha. good try tho. Your comment explains why it is incorrect and the several references to the puzzle being hard is further proof for that.